# How to have words within an HTML search box delete themselves upon focus on iOS

Tags: javascript, html

I've Googled around a bit for this, but it's a little hard to search for because of its specificity.

I have an HTML search box on my site (made with a simple HTML form/table). I want to have the word "Search" inside of the text box to make it look nicer (as opposed to having it to the left of the search box). I also have the focus set to that search box upon page load, so as soon as you load the page, your cursor is placed inside that text box.

Now, that is the behavior on a desktop OS, but on iOS the page does not load with the cursor inside, and thus the text is not auto-selected.

What I want to know is how to have the "Search" text delete itself upon tapping on the search box.

Again, I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate post, but I couldn't find anything from searching.

Comment: Please post your code!? also, your question is unclear - if you are relying on a default browser behaviour then you might be disappointed by the results, you should be using a tiny bit of javascript/jQuery for this.

Comment: This is what I use to position the cursor: `<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('moviesearchinput').focus()</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use CSS to make the text light and grey, and position it behind the textbox.  Then you can use javascript to hide the text.

Thanks,

Max 

Comment: I think it's the only way - but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function to call on page load using `onload` in the `<body>` tag like so..

Put this somewhere in your `<head>`

```
<script>

  function focusOnTextBox(){

    //Get the textbox element
    var textBox = document.getElementById('moviesearchinput');

    //Focus on the textBox.
    textBox.focus();

    //Empty the value of the textbox.
    textBox.value = "";

  }

</script>
```

Then change your opening `<body>` tag to look like this

```
<body onload="focusOnTextBox();">
```

Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate this working - http://jsfiddle.net/kp5br/